# Android: Service won't bind

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create bound service. As a test I created service which plays music:

```
public class MusicService extends Service {
    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return myBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.teardrop);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        player.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }    
}
```

And when I bind it from Activity nothing happens:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabSwipeActivity {
    boolean isBound = false;
    MusicService myService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Some code        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        if(isBound){
            Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "bind failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        }       
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            isBound = false;
        }
    };    
}
```

Service is registred in manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MusicService" />
```

Bind failed appears and nothing happens

EDIT: bindService() returns false

EDIT2: when I add complete name in manifest eg. com.mypackage.mypackage2.MusicService
bind Service() returned true. But onServiceConnected() is never called.

Next question is: When I create service which implements LocationListener, what should I use to send message to activity everytime when onLocationChanged()?

Comment: Check return value of `bindService()`, methods in `ServiceConnection` may be called too late

Comment: The service tag is within the <application> tag right?

Comment: bindService() returns false

Comment: _"But onServiceConnected() is never called"_ Did you use logging or debugger to test that?

Comment: I used Log and Toast. Music doesn't play and I can't call methods of service.. NullPointer Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already know the solution. I extends `TabActivity` made by `actionBarSherlock` instead of `Activity`. This is known issue:

```
 getApplicationContext().bindService();
```

fix that.